# Remove specific tags from HTML using PHP and dump into array

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, dom

**Problem:**

I use Simple HTML DOM and I would like to strip certain information from a HTML code I managed to extract from a web page. The rest of the code should go into an array.

**The PHP code:**

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.dn.se');

    $results = $html->find('ul[class=list]', 1);

    echo $results;
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Mest delat och rekommenderat på DN.se</li>

    <li><a href="/nyheter/varlden/polis-misstog-blind-for-samuraj"><span class="number">1.</span> Polis misstog blind för samuraj<br>
    <span class="metadata">I går</span></a> <span class="sharetooltip  init-done" data-url="" style="display:inline-block;"><a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">868</a> <span class="tooltip"><span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">35</span> tweets</span> <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">833</span> rekommendationer</span></span></span></li>

    <li><a href="/debatt/s-vill-ha-tioarig-skolplikt-och-farre-elever-i-klassen"><span class="number">2.</span> ”S vill ha tioårig skolplikt och färre elever i klassen”<br>
    <span class="metadata">I går</span></a> <span class="sharetooltip  init-done" data-url="" style="display:inline-block;"><a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">671</a> <span class="tooltip"><span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">77</span> tweets</span> <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">594</span> rekommendationer</span></span></span></li>

    <li><a href="/sthlm/edholm-backar-om-skolornas-smorforbud"><span class="number">3.</span> Edholm backar om skolornas smörförbud<br>
    <span class="metadata">16 okt</span></a> <span class="sharetooltip  init-done" data-url="" style="display:inline-block;"><a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">604</a> <span class="tooltip"><span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">33</span> tweets</span> <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">571</span> rekommendationer</span></span></span></li>
</ul>
```

**Desired array structure:**

Iterative parent/children, starting with < ul> as a parent.

**Desired output:**

```
Array 
{
    [0] => <li>Mest delat och rekommenderat på DN.se</li>
    [1] => <li><a href="/nyheter/varlden/polis-misstog-blind-for-samuraj">1. Polis misstog blind för samuraj</a></li>
        [0] => <a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">868</a>
        [1] => <span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">35</span> tweets</span>
        [2] => <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">833</span> rekommendationer</span></span>
    [2] => <li><a href="/debatt/s-vill-ha-tioarig-skolplikt-och-farre-elever-i-klassen">2. ”S vill ha tioårig skolplikt och färre elever i klassen”</a></li>
        [0] => <a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">671</a>
        [1] => <span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">77</span> tweets</span>
        [2] => <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">594</span> rekommendationer</span></span>
    [3] => <li><a href="/sthlm/edholm-backar-om-skolornas-smorforbud">3. Edholm backar om skolornas smörförbud</a></li>
        [0] => <a class="sharecount" href="javascript:void(0);">604</a>
        [1] => <span class="counter twit"><span class="twitcount">33</span> tweets</span>
        [2] => <span class="counter fb"><span class="fbcount">571</span> rekommendationer</span></span>
}
```

Comment: What do you want the values in your array to be?

Comment: Do you want to remove those `<a>` and `<span>` tags inside each `<li>`? Could you write the desired output?

Comment: I have now added a desired output in an array.

Comment: So what does this `$results = $html->find('ul[class=list]', 1);` give you exactly?

Comment: It gives me the abovementioned HTML code, which is stored in $results. Then I want to take $results and walk through it so the desired array can be generated.

Comment: "I would like to strip certain information from a HTML code, […] the rest of the code should go into an array." So you don't need to strip anything but only extract the needed code parts.